# ndk r20 ld : ld: error: cannot find -lpthread

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, tesseract, ld

I'm trying to build tesseract for android arm with vcpkg and ndk r20
I had to edit CMakeLists.txt and add glob.c and glob.h because they weren't in the ndk

I also made fileio.cpp include glob.h

then I had to bypass pkg-config because ndk doesn't have it
I replace this :

```
if(NOT EXISTS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/.cppan)
    if (NOT Leptonica_DIR AND NOT MSVC)
        find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
        pkg_check_modules(Leptonica REQUIRED lept>=${MINIMUM_LEPTONICA_VERSION})
        #link_directories(${Leptonica_LIBRARY_DIRS})
    else()
        find_package(Leptonica ${MINIMUM_LEPTONICA_VERSION} REQUIRED CONFIG)
    endif()
else()
    if (STATIC)
        set(CPPAN_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS 0)
    else()
        set(CPPAN_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS 1)
    endif()
    add_subdirectory(.cppan)
endif()
```

with this :

```
if(NOT EXISTS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/.cppan)
    if (NOT Leptonica_DIR AND NOT MSVC)
        find_package(Leptonica CONFIG REQUIRED)
        #link_libraries(tesseract leptonica) causes errors , tried tesseractlib instead of tesseract
    else()
        find_package(Leptonica ${MINIMUM_LEPTONICA_VERSION} REQUIRED CONFIG)
    endif()
else()
    if (STATIC)
        set(CPPAN_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS 0)
    else()
        set(CPPAN_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS 1)
    endif()
    add_subdirectory(.cppan)
endif()
```

after this I tried to build the library with this command :

```
vcpkg install tesseract[core]:arm-android
```

the build process exits due to error near the end
the libtesseract.a library is built but not the binary tesseract

there is a long log in install-arm-android-rel-out.log and this is the error at the end :

```
[240/242] cmd.exe /C "cd . && E:\programs\vcpkg\downloads\tools\cmake-3.14.0-windows\cmake-3.14.0-win32-x86\bin\cmake.exe -E remove libtesseract.a && E:\programs\ndk\android-ndk-r20\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ar.exe qc libtesseract.a  @CMakeFiles\libtesseract.rsp && E:\programs\ndk\android-ndk-r20\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib.exe libtesseract.a && cd ."
[241/242] cmd.exe /C "cd . && E:\programs\ndk\android-ndk-r20\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi21 --gcc-toolchain=E:/programs/ndk/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=E:/programs/ndk/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot  -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-addrsig -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -frtti -fexceptions  --std=c++11 -Oz -DNDEBUG  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind.a -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--gc-sections CMakeFiles/tesseract.dir/src/api/tesseractmain.cpp.o  -o bin\tesseract  libtesseract.a -lpthread E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/lib/libleptonica.a E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/lib/libgif.a E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/lib/libjpeg.a E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/share/png/../../lib/libpng16.a E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/lib/libtiff.a E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/lib/liblzma.a E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/lib/libjpeg.a E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/share/png/../../lib/libpng16.a E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/lib/libtiff.a E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/lib/liblzma.a E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/lib/libz.a -lm E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/lib/libz.a -lm -latomic -lm && cd ."
FAILED: bin/tesseract 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && E:\programs\ndk\android-ndk-r20\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi21 --gcc-toolchain=E:/programs/ndk/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=E:/programs/ndk/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot  -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-addrsig -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -frtti -fexceptions  --std=c++11 -Oz -DNDEBUG  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind.a -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--gc-sections CMakeFiles/tesseract.dir/src/api/tesseractmain.cpp.o  -o bin\tesseract  libtesseract.a -lpthread E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/lib/libleptonica.a E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/lib/libgif.a E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/lib/libjpeg.a E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/share/png/../../lib/libpng16.a E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/lib/libtiff.a E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/lib/liblzma.a E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/lib/libjpeg.a E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/share/png/../../lib/libpng16.a E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/lib/libtiff.a E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/lib/liblzma.a E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/lib/libz.a -lm E:/programs/vcpkg/installed/arm-android/lib/libz.a -lm -latomic -lm && cd ."
E:/programs/ndk/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: error: cannot find -lpthread
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

as you can see the linker can't find pthread !

this is my arm-android.cmake used by vcpkg :

```
set(VCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE arm)
set(VCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE dynamic)
set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE static)

set(VCPKG_CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)
set(VCPKG_BUILD_TYPE release)
```

and I set these variables :

```
set "ANDROID_NDK=E:\programs\ndk\android-ndk-r20\"
set "ANDROID_NDK_HOME=E:\programs\ndk\android-ndk-r20\"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need glob. After all, you are building for a mobile device, where you won't perform training. The file `fileio.cpp` that refers to glob, is only used in training.

Android NDK is special in that it does not have libpthread, the pthread implementation is inside libc. The easy hack is to <s>copy libc.a to libpthread.a, or</s> create an empty libpthread.a with **ar** command.

You may find the preconfigured [docker build environment](https://github.com/rhardih/bad/tree/master/tesseract) helpful. If you prefer an ndk-build version, fully integrated into Android Studio, have a look at my fork: https://github.com/alexcohn/tess-two.

Comment: I tried copying libc.a to libpthread.a but now there is symbols duplicate . can you tell me how to create an empty library with ar command

Comment: `libc.a` is a static library containing the basic C functions. `libpthread.a` is the static version of the Posix `pthread` library. You'll be unsuccessful in 99.9...% of the time if you randomly copy one library with a completely different set of functions and hope it'll magically replace what a library with a whole different purpose serves - and you'll get duplicate symbols if you link with both of them. Linking with `libc.a` is built-in.

Comment: I created an empty libpthread.a with : 'arm-dontremeber-ar.exe cr libpthread.a' and it worked . @Alex-Cohn what do you mean with training ? do you mean using the languages files from tesseract repository or something else ?

Comment: Cool that now it works: I was offline and could not answer you question timely.

Comment: @TedLyngmo my mistake was that in this particular case, the linker had both libc.a (under the name of libpthread.a) and libc.so. Your pitch is generally correct, but the Android NDK is that 0.01% because here, libc includes all libpthread symbols. Methinks this wasn't a wise choice of people who created NDK, but after 10 years, it's too late to rebel.

Comment: **re: training** — tesseract's main CMakeList.txt recognizes `-DBUILD_TRAINING_TOOLS=OFF`, but default is `ON`. The [training](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract-4.00) covers adding new languages, fonts, or logic to the new neural network-based recognition engine. According to the Wiki above (I am not sure how up-to-date it is), training only works on Linux, and may take a few days to a couple of weeks with OpenMP and Intel Intrinsics support for SSE/AVX extensions. So there is no point in compiling the training-only code (e.g. **fileio.cpp**) for Android.